# How to get count from the list of values within parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings.

```
   Str1 = "LeapYearTests, LeapYearParameterizedTestFixture,
    ::testing::Values(1, 711, 1989, 2013)";

   Str2 = "LeapYearTests,LeapYearMultipleParametersTests,
    ::testing::Values(
            std::make_tuple(7, false),
            std::make_tuple(2001, false),
            std::make_tuple(1996, true),
            std::make_tuple(1700, false),
            std::make_tuple(1600, true))"
```

I need to extract number of values present within "Values()".

For Str1 expected output is 4  for (1, 711, 1989, 2013)

For Str2 expected output is 5  for (std::make_tuple(7, false),  std::make_tuple(2001, false), std::make_tuple(1996, true),
std::make_tuple(1700, false),
std::make_tuple(1600, true))

I have used the below sample java code which works for Str1 but fails for Str2.

```
int start = Str1.indexOf("Values(") + 7;
int end = Str1.lastIndexOf(")");
String result = Str1.substring(start, end);
int count = result.split(",").length;
```

Please suggest some sample code or regex that works for both the strings.

Comment: Will there ever be numbers outside of the `Values()`? (It doesn't look like it from your examples) Because if not, why not simply regex find and count `\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class stackoverflow {

    public static int getNrOfValues(String str) {
        int nrofvalues = 0;
        if(!str.matches("make_touple")) {
            int start = str.indexOf("Values(") + 7;
            int end = str.lastIndexOf(")");
            String result = str.substring(start, end);
            nrofvalues = result.split(",").length;

        } else {

            int start = str.indexOf("make_touple(");
            int end = str.lastIndexOf(")");
            String result = str.substring(start, end);
            nrofvalues = ((result.split("std::make_tuple").length));
        }

        return nrofvalues;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String  Str1 = "LeapYearTests, LeapYearParameterizedTestFixture,::testing::Values(1, 711, 1989, 2013)";

      String  Str2 = "LeapYearTests,LeapYearMultipleParametersTests, ::testing::Values( std::make_tuple(7, false), std::make_tuple(2001, false), std::make_tuple(1996, true), std::make_tuple(1700, false), std::make_tuple(1600, true))";

      System.out.println(stackoverflow.getNrOfValues(Str1));
      System.out.println(stackoverflow.getNrOfValues(Str2) / 2);


    }

}
```

Something like this, but you need to figure how to divide by 2

Answer (score 0):

My solution is given below:

```
private static int getNumOfValues(String str) {
    int idx = str.indexOf("testing::Values");
    str = str.substring(idx,str.length());
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    int nrofvalues = 0;
    System.out.println(str);
    for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == '('){
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i) == ',' && stack.size() == 1){
            nrofvalues++;
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i) == ')'){
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    return nrofvalues + 1;
}
```